# AbstractMethodError when using Jadiru Joda/Hibernate persistent user types

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've introduced a "created" column to my user's database of MySQL TIMESTAMP type.  I'm attempting to map this to a Joda LocalDateTime using Jadiru's UserType Hibernate mappers.  I'm using v2.0 of the UserType classes and I've tried with v 3.6.0 and 3.6.7 of Hibernate.  I'm using JDK 1.6.  This data access layer is being used as part of a Spring 3 web application.

Here's the relevant bit of my persistence object -

```
@Column(name = "created")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime") 
private LocalDateTime created;
```

Nothing too complicated, but I get the following exception whenever my UserDAO tries to query the table -

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime.nullSafeGet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:908)
        at com.vox.dao.UserDAO.getUser(UserDAO.java:27)
        at com.vox.security.DashboardAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(DashboardAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:30)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

I've tried placing all annotations on the methods instead of fields, but same issue.

I've also tried mapping different column types, like DATE to a LocalDate and TIME to a LocalTIME but each gives a similar error.

Another thing I tried was using a criteria query instead of a template based query.  This didn't affect the problem.

I've checked the classpath for duplicate libraries, which there do not appear to be.

Something is clearly wrong with my setup, as the UserType documentation says this should just work.  No google hits for this error whatsoever.  Please can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a solution but a pointer/hint: the signature of `nullSafeGet` looks strange. It should be

```
public T nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet,
                 String[] strings,
                 org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor session,
                 Object object)
          throws SQLException
```

but hibernate calls a `nullSafeGet` without the `SessionImplementor` parameter. So the actual `CustomType` class might define an abstract `nullSafeGet` method which isn't implemented in the actual implementor `PersistentLocalDateTime` (which simply implements a method with different parameters)

Maybe your versions of joda and hibernate are not compatible. I'd investigate in that direction again.

Comment: Andreas, Thank you for your answer.  You were spot on - the version of UserType I was using (2.0) is listed as compatible with Hibernate 4 in the release notes.  The exception goes away when I use version 1.9 of this library, which appears to be the last supported release for Hibernate 3.6.

Comment: Thanks! had the same problem. This helped save a lot of time.

Comment: Hi! What piece of code did you put inside your pom.xml in order do import the 1.9 version correctly?

Answer (score 1):

in reply to "What piece of code did you put inside your pom.xml in order do import the 1.9 version correctly?" by Renato Gama, try

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
  <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```